# Настройка отношения one to zero-or-one совместно с one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть работающее приложение/вебсайт, в котором можно в паспорт автомобиля подгружать картинки, одна из картинок считается "заглавной". Первая загруженная картинка становится заглавной, впоследствии можно поменять.

Соответственно, были следующие классы:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

И как-то знакомые предложили мне попробовать отрефакторить это следующим образом: не помечать заглавную картинку как IsPrimaryImage = true, а вынести в свойство PrimaryImage:

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

Однако чем больше я вникаю в эту задачу - тем больше понимаю, что она не такая простая как мне показалось на первый взгляд.

Сначала я думал обойтись только data anntotation (не очень люблю fluent API, когда определения где-то отдельно от таблиц), есть [мой топик на en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640913/), где я пытался расставить атрибуты.

Однако проблемы начались когда я начал пытаться сохраниться в базу:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var car = db.Car.First(x => x.ID == CarID);

    var image = new CarImage
    {
        CarID = car.ID,
        //Car = car,
        IsDeleted = false,
    };

    db.CarImages.Add(image);

    db.SaveChanges();

    if (isFirstImage)
    {
        car.PrimaryImage = image;
        car.PrimaryImageID = image.ID;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(Ошибок было много разных, могу привести, но как мне кажется, что там нет ничего полезного для дальнейшего обсуждения)

После чего я решил оставить эти попытки и использовать fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CarImages>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Car)
    .WithOptional(x => x.PrimaryImage)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("PrimaryImageID"));
```

И... тоже как ни странно стал получать те или иные ошибки. Тоже не привожу, т.к. в этот момент я понял, что нужно разбираться основательно и сначала.

Итак, для начала разберёмся с [отношениями в базе](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

У одного автомобиля может быть несколько изображений -- это очевидно, связь one-to-many.

Но, с другой стороны, у каждого автомобиля может быть одна заглавная картинка -- это очевидно связь one to zero-or-one.

Как правильно прописать эти связки в моих классах?

В контроле у меня собственно всего лишь две вьюхи:

- нужно вывести список машин с заглавными картинками (или картинкой-заглушкой, если картинок ещё нет);
- нужно вывести карточку машины со списком параметров и всеми картинками, которые относятся к этой машине.

И, как раз в первой будут намного лучше план запроса к БД, если сделать рефакторинг.

Пробовал такой вариант решения:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? PrimaryImageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PrimaryImageID")]
    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarImage> AllImages { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
public class CarImage
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarID")]
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

я [описывал в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34938319#34938319), как я к нему шёл, там же можно найти проблемы, с которыми я столкнулся и пока не смог решить.

Comment: У вас две разные связи - а вы их описали как одну. Отсюда и проблема.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы слишком все усложнили. Атрибут

```
[ForeignKey("Car")]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Т.е. ок, вы скопировали его из статьи про one-to-one or zero - но нужно понимать, за счет чего достигается эта связь.

По сути, вы просто говорите "ID картинки должен быть равен ID существующей машины". Достаточно очевидно, что при этом у машины может быть не больше одной картинки. Вы физически не можете записать в базу картинку с ID = 2, если в базе нет машины с ID = 2. Никак. Вы явно обозначили это в своей модели. В вашей модели в базе не может быть ровно одна машина и две картинки - то ID у картинок должны быть равны, и вы просто не сможете их различить.

И тут же вы пытаетесь заявить "но у машины (как-то!) может быть несколько картинок!" - что делает вашу модель противоречивой. И EF умирает.

Не усложняйте. Просто уберите лишнее - лишние атрибуты, лишние вызовы SaveChanges, возможность достать машину из CarImage (можно оставить, но скорее всего она не нужна) и оставить работу через сущности - все заработает именно так, как вы хотите. Вот минимальный рабочий пример:

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CarImage> AllImages { get; set; }
}

public class CarImage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new Model1())
{
    var car = db.Cars.First(x => x.ID == 1);
    bool isFirstImage = !car.AllImages.Any();

    var image = new CarImage();

    car.AllImages.Add(image);

    if (isFirstImage)
    {
        car.PrimaryImage = image;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

По желанию можно вернут на место все `PrimaryImageId`, `CarID`, `Car` `DbSet<CarImage>` - все будет работать точно так же (т.е. вы этим сможете явно сделать это позволит вам сделать связь `CarImage -> Car` обязательной, но сейчас она все равно практически обязательна - т.к. у `CarImage` нет `Car` - вы не можете его занулить :) )

[image: ssms]

Comment: Да, это [работает](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35014401#35014401) именно так, как хотелось.

Answer (score 0):

Классы, приведенные в вопросе выглядят правильными, и должны по идее решать поставленную задачу. Следует только на уровне приложения следить за тем, чтобы PrimaryImage у разных машин не ссылался на один и тот же CarImage, и чтобы этот CarImage в свою очередь ссылался именно на эту машину. Такую логику хорошо бы поместить прямо в свойство PrimaryImage (Entity Framework позволяет так делать).

```
private CarImage fPrimaryImage;
public virtual CarImage PrimaryImage {
  get { return fPrimaryImage; }
  set {
    if (fPrimaryImage == value) return;
    fPrimaryImage = value;
    if (fPrimaryImage != null)
      fPrimaryImage.Car = this;
  }
```

Можно сделать еще такую вещь - добавить таблицу в которой хранить ссылки на Car и CarImage. В этой таблице хранить PrimaryImage всех машин. При таком подходе, будет сложнее запутаться при объявлении one to zero-or-one связи.

```
public class Car {
    public virtual PrimaryImage PrimaryImage {get;set;}
}
public class CarImage {
  [Required]
  public virtual Car Car { get;set;}
}
public class PrimaryImage {
  [Required]
  public virtual Car Car {get;set;}
  [Required]
  public virtual CarImage Image {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Дополнительная таблица для хранения PrimaryImage каждых машин -- решение понятное и логичное, хотя и явно избыточное: связь один-к-одному, достаточно nullable поля на таблице машин. В реальных проектах я бы не стал пользоваться таким подходом.