# EF создать связь 1к0 и 1 к многим одновременно

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Не могу одновременно создать связи между группой и студентами и группой и старостой класса студент.

```
[DataContract]
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Students = new List<StudentProfile>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentProfile> Students { get; set; }
    //public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MonitorId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual StudentProfile Monitor { get; set; } // starosta
}


[DataContract]
public class StudentProfile : ClientProfile
{
    [DataMember]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Когда удаляю код со связями 1 ко многим, то работает 1к0, и когда удалю 1к0 работает 1кМногим.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentProfile>()
.HasOptional(c => c.Group)
.WithMany(c => c.Students);

 modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
.HasRequired(w => w.Monitor)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(m => m.MonitorId);
```

Запросы:

```
Group g = new Group() { Name="IT-41" };
StudentProfile a = new StudentProfile() { Id = user.Id };
StudentProfile a1 = new StudentProfile() { Id = user1.Id };
//TeacherProfile a2 = new TeacherProfile() { Id = user2.Id };
a.Name = "Nazar";
a.MiddleName = "Victorovich";
a.Surname = "Kalytiuk";
a1.Name = "Serg";
a1.MiddleName = "Daddy";
a1.Surname = "Romanchuk";
//a2.Name = "Petro";
//a2.MiddleName = "Oleks";
//a2.Surname = "Katin";
g.Monitor = a;
//g.Students = new List<StudentProfile>() { a, a1 };
a.Group = g;
a1.Group = g;
//a.MonitoringGroup = g;
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Groups.Add(g);
db.Students.Add(a);
db.Students.Add(a1);
//db.Teachers.Add(a2);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Пример не похож тем, что у студента есть ссылка на группу, а у CarImage нет ссылки на Car.

Comment: Недавно спрашивал очень похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617713/213987

Comment: Я просто хочу иметь возможность возвращать Id, а не объект. Или нужно объект? Когда у меня на пример запрос на групу, то вернуть только Id старосты, а не весь объект. web api

Comment: Подождите, давайте сначала. Что означают ваши "удаляю, то работает... когда то-то то работает"? Ошибки есть? Какие? Это первое. Второе: пример в моём вопросе повторяет ваш один-в-один, у группы может быть много студентов (у машины может быть много картинок) и у группы может быть только один староста (у машины может быть только одна заглавная картинка). И третье: если у вас ошибки на запросах -- то приведите тексты запросов, потому что я проблемы не вижу: не хотите получать весь объект - не получайте, не пишите Include, делов-то? Вообще, вы много пишете постулатов, но не пишите деталей. А надо.

Comment: Когда я удаляю в класе групы поле старосты, то все работет. Или когда удаляю у студента группу и у группы список студентов то тоже все работает. Я имею ввиду что нормально добавляется староста или группа студента, но не вместе

Comment: Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values. Вот это чаще всего вылетает

Comment: И все телепаты сразу поняли, каким кодом вы добавляете старосту и группу. Может приведёте наконец-то сбойные запросы не удаляя никакие поля? Кнопка "править" на сообщении. Не надо много комментариев расписывать -- добавляйте информацию в вопрос. У вас нет пока вопроса как такового -- отвечать просто не на что, вопрос нужно закрыть как "непонятна суть вопроса", таких на сайте очень много.

Comment: А почему вы перед тем как сделать `g.Monitor = a;` не делаете `db.Students.Add(a);db.SaveChanges();`? У вас же ещё нет присвоенных идентификаторов.

Comment: Да, в этом и была проблема. Теперь все работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А почему вы перед тем как сделать `g.Monitor = a;` не делаете `db.Students.Add(a);db.SaveChanges();`?

У вас же ещё нет присвоенных идентификаторов.

Сначала нужно сохранить объект старосты, а потом уже добавлять в группу.

Вот тут посмотрите пример: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35015089#35015089